# How to switch 'standard' installation profile to 'minimal' in existing site?

Tags: 8, installation-profiles

I have built a druapl 8 site with 'Standard' installation profile.

How can I  switch 'standard' installation profile to 'minimal' in existing site?

Comment: There is no "switching" installation profiles. There is a variable that describes what installation profile was used during install. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Do you need to uninstall modules or remove content that was installed by the standard installation profile? Please clarify your question.

Comment: The installation profile defines a set of modules, permissions and variables to create/enable. If you created it with standard, you can strip down to minimal by disabling some modules and removing permissions and variables. Otherwise start over.

Comment: @mradcliffe I'm trying to uninstall module of current activated installation profile. But no modules can be uninstalled directly until and unless their internal content doesn't get deleted. My target is to activate 'minimal' profile which have only `node`, `block`, `dblog`, `page_cache`, `dynamic_page_cache` modules.

Comment: From my experience minimal installation is just a big headache. It's a lot easier to use normal installation and then just uninstall modules that you don't need.

Comment: There is a possibility of switching profiles, FYI—I had to do this one one particular site to get a few of the Lightning distribution's features to work correctly. Here are the instructions for how I did it: https://www.drupal.org/node/2677722#comment-11843563

Comment: there is a module in Drupal7 to do that: https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_switcher For the case of Drupal8, I just commited a patch which uses a drush command to update the profile: https://www.drupal.org/node/2867180#comment-12277386

Comment: Use this script: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2677722#comment-12815008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installation profiles contain code to set up a site during installation, that's all they do. They aren't useful to an installed site.

Trying to change the profile *after* installation could never conceptually do anything. The installation code has already run, and the purpose of the profile has been served at that point.

Comment: For the most part, yes—however, Drupal still tracks the installed profile, and will run update hooks defined in that profile's .install file. Sometimes people install a site with one profile and need/want to switch to another, or to standard/minimal to get out of the cycle of updating that profile...

Comment: @geerlingguy I didn't know about the update hooks, thanks!

Comment: Switching profiles is not supported use case and you better know what you do. Having said that, we now have https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_switcher

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to switch
 you have two solution,

- install again
- remove standard modules.

[lists the modules enabled by the Standard profile, as compared to the Minimal profile](https://www.drupal.org/node/1127786)